# Laravel Pusher not working in Production

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pusher

I have a working Laravel-Pusher app, with Pusher's Sandbox(free) account. Pusher gave me three (development, staging, production) in my 1 Pusher app. But when I pushed to production, it seems it can't connect to Pusher. I don't get any errors in the browser console, or in my Laravel log, but it shows it is successfully broadcasting. I am using the three (development, staging, production) interchangeably, but nothing works. This works perfectly on my local machine.

Here is my Laravel log:

> [2017-06-21 23:26:41] local.INFO: Broadcasting [App\Events\Feedback\Feedback] on channels [delete-feedback] with payload:
>   {
>       "id": "59"
>   }

Does it mean sandbox will not work in production?

Comment: Have you enabled pusher debug in your javascript code? Maybe it's a config caching issue...

Answer (score 0):

On the Pusher "Create your app" form, you checked the "Create apps for multiple environments?" checkbox:

[image]

> Pusher gave me three (development, staging, production) in my 1 Pusher app.

This checkbox means that you created *three separate Pusher apps*, not just one. Each of these apps will have its own name, app ID, app key, and app secret. You will need to configure each of your environments to use the appropriate Pusher app. For example, your production Laravel app will need to be configured with the app ID, key, and secret of your `foobar-production` Pusher app.

Answer (score -1):

Check the timezone of your localhost and your prod server.
Some people (and me now lol) face this problem.